# How to confirm the subscription of Amazon SNS without having the endpoint token?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

In my JAVA application, I'm using Amazon SNS to send emails to customer; Once I subscribe one customer(email id) into my SNS Topic; It is asking the customer to confirm the subscription to receive the emails;

Is there any way to confirm the subscription in our application itself(without cusstomer's help)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

The entire point of the confirmation step is to force the end user to confirm the subscription so that SNS cannot be used as a spamming mechanism.  If SNS allowed the application developer to confirm subscriptions without access to the endpoint token, then you could confirm anyone's email address.

Note however, that SNS could technically implement a feature which would allow the email owner to confirm subscriptions for your account, so that if your application will be subscribing and unsubscribing an email address from lots of topics, they wouldn't have to confirm each one.  Sadly, that feature currently doesn't exist.

One other possibility which would actually give you what you need is if SNS allowed you to send emails from your SES account and use your SES trust level.  Again, this feature doesn't exist currently.

Until the SNS team delivers a feature which allows this use case, if you need to deliver to customers, you could allow SNS to do the fanout for you to HTTP or SQS queues, then deliver emails from those notification using SES.

Comment: Actually,  I need to subscribe the same email id for multiple topics; so every time the customer is getting emails when they subscribed to different topic.  My requirement is,  Once if the customer confirmed the subscription for a topic it should always activate the subscription for all the topics (without email confirmation);  Any advice??

Comment: @Vijay, Like I said, there is nothing you can currently do using just SNS.  My recommendation would be to post your use case to the SNS forums (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=72).  This is a use case that the SNS team is aware of, so the more noise they hear, the more likely it is that they will implement a solution.    I'll also update my answer with something you can do now to give you the functionality needed.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Also I posted this question in [SNS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=133023&tstart=0). Let you know once I got solution :-)

Comment: Do you know how to set the AuthenticateOnUnsubscribe flag in Java application? As I mentioned earlier I am using SNS for sending email to customer, So the token value may not be received(Not sure; If possible, Advice me)

Comment: @Vijay, For the authenticate on unsubscribe flag to be set, I believe you need to confirm the subscription with an authenticated request (AKA, authenticated with your AWS creds).   NOTE:  This is a different question and should be posted as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a suggestion, you can use Amazon Pinpoint to send emails to non-verified addresses (after moving out of sandbox). See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/channels-email-setup-production-access.html