# How to get an sns token using email protocl

Tags: java, amazon-sns

Hello does anyone know how to get an access token for a sns email endpoint. please need your help. Havent any tutorial on this. This is a web app trying to push notifications to my client emails

```
public class EmailNotifications {

private static final String accessKey = "";
private static final String secretAccess ="";


public static void SignUP(String email, String Topic){
    AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretAccess));
    snsClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_1));

    //create a Topic
    CreateTopicRequest createTopicRequest = new CreateTopicRequest().withName(Topic);
    CreateTopicResult createTopicResult = snsClient.createTopic(createTopicRequest);

    //subscribes to a topic
    SubscribeRequest subscribeRequest = new SubscribeRequest().withTopicArn(createTopicResult.getTopicArn())
                                                                .withProtocol("email").withEndpoint(email);
   /*SubscribeResult rr= */snsClient.subscribe(subscribeRequest);



   ConfirmSubscriptionRequest confirmSubscriptionRequest = new ConfirmSubscriptionRequest().withTopicArn(createTopicResult.getTopicArn());
   // ConfirmSubscriptionResult confirmSubscriptionResult = snsClient.
    //confirmSubscriptionResult.getSubscriptionArn();
    String token = confirmSubscriptionRequest.getToken();
    ConfirmSubscriptionResult confirmSubscriptionResult = snsClient.confirmSubscription(createTopicResult.getTopicArn(), token);

    //PublishRequest
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an [API here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNS.html) read it carefully.

To verify sns end use [confirmSubscription](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNS.html#confirmSubscription(com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.ConfirmSubscriptionRequest)).

> Verifies an endpoint owner's intent to receive messages by validating the token sent to the endpoint by an earlier Subscribe action.

Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201594/how-to-confirm-the-subscription-of-amazon-sns-without-having-the-endpoint-token) may help.

Comment: please i just added my code. please could you let me know if im on the right track. Thank you